# How to create viewmodel with 2 differents models

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i want to create a viewmodel to access in my view to two differents models i have created.

For this i create two diferrents models and one model which i include both.

My problem is that in my view i can´t access the data.

hope that anybody can help with this.

What i need to represented in my view are:
Table1 :
name
title

Table2:
picpath of each image

here is my code:

**model 1:**

```
 public class Table1
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string name{ get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string edition{ get; set; }
        public string number{ get; set; }

    }

   public class DefaultConnection : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Table1> Res{ get; set; }
    }
```

**model 2:**

```
 public class Images
    {
        public SelectList ImageList { get; set; }   
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string title{ get; set; }
        public string picpath { get; set; }

        public Img)
        {
            ImageList = GetImages();
        }

        public SelectList GetImages()
        {
            var list = new List<SelectListItem>();
            string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

            using (var con = new SqlConnection(connection))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Myimages", con))
                {
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string title = reader[1] as string;
                        string imagePath = reader[2] as string;
                        list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = title, Value = imagePath });
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            return new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text");
        }

    }
```

**MY VIEW Model:**

```
 public class ViewModel
    {
        public Table1 table1{ get; set; }
        public Images xpto { get; set; }

        public ViewModel(Table1 table1)
        {
            Table1 = table1;
            xpto = new Images();
        }
    }



**Controller:**

 public ActionResult HotSpotMaker(int id = 0)
        {
            Table1 rev = db.Res.Find(id);          
            if (rev == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
//Here is something missing, have delete my version here because don´t make any sense
            return View(rev);
        }
```

**View:**

```
  @model myproject.Models.ViewModel
```

Note:  i search a lot, and find that a lot of people use this: @model myproject.Web.Models.ViewModel  ,   but i can´t select this web. . i don´t know if this is relevant or not, i thought maybe is important to say it.

Comment: You can refer to mine question for 2 different way to achieve the goal. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502294/what-is-the-proper-way-to-submit-data-from-parent-form-with-partial-view-mvc-4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing `Table1` in as the view model, but that's not your view model.

Try:

```
return View(new Models.ViewModel(rev));
```

Comment: hmm ok... but now i have another error:  ViewModel does not contain a definition for "name" and doesn´t accept a first argument of type ViewModel because not found

Comment: @user2232273, then somewhere (perhaps in the view) you are calling `name` on the model, but it doesn't have a name property.  It has `table1` and `xpto`, so I suspect you need to call `@Model.table1.name`.

Comment: thx it works...  in my i had this @Html.DisplayFor(model=> model.name) and change it to @table1.xpto.name ..thx a lot

Answer (score 1):

Well it's rather simple, your `View` is expecting a `ViewModel` (that's a bad name by the way, but I suspect it's just a test), but you are giving it a `Table1`, your view simply doesn't know what to do with it.

You need a method to create a `ViewModel` object from a `Table1` object

In your case just call your constructor like so

```
return View(new ViewModel(rev));
```

Comment: thx simon for the post.. the name viewmodel is only a test.. i try to understand how this works in mvc 4.....  i have try it but give another error now.. can you pls see my comment to @moo-juice... i explain what is the error now

Comment: That's because your view is malformed, you need to do more than just change `@using myproject.Models.Table1` to `@using myproject.Models.ViewModel`, your `ViewModel` object don't have a name property, it does however contain a `Table1` object that do.
Try changing stuff in your view like  `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)` by `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.table1.name)`
Remember that view models are nothing special, they are just plain simple object, "view model" is just a naming convention to designate their role

Comment: yep, i have make a change in my view... i had this before @Html.DisplayFor(model=> model.n_empresa) , but this doesn´t work.. i change it to this @table.xpto.name...

Comment: I recommend sticking to using `@Html.DisplayFor`, even for displaying simple text, the reason for that is that ASP has a lovely mechanism called **display template** (and his friend the **editor template**) that will allow to reuse specific code without copy/pasting it, always displaying a specific set of symbols for booleans for example, or even a whole object, it's pretty awesome